# Что должно быть в

Tags: delphi

Delphi
Мне нужно вывести в TEdit вектор из 5 целых чисел

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос яснее.

Comment: Мне нужно вывести в TEdit вектор из 5 целых чисел.

Comment: @andreycha  Мне нужно вывести в TEdit вектор из 5 целых чисел

Comment: Подойдите, пожалуйста, более серьезно к формулировке вопроса. Почитайте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
var a:array [1..5] of integer;
i:integer;
s:string;
begin
  s := '';
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    s := s + ' ' + inttostr(a[i]);
  edit1.text := s;
end;
```

Comment: а какие параметры будут у функции:

Comment: мне же надо рекурсивно

Comment: Вам не нужно рекурсивно.
а фунция - это лишь заготовка. Учитесь применять.

Comment: если честно , то я не очень понял. Как это будет все выглядеть?